# How to implement Angular style config and run phases in a Vue application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Coming to Vue from Angular I'm having trouble working out how you allow components and "services" (e.g. JS singleton classes) to be configured as the app is bootstrapped.

Angular has the ability to specify .config() blocks throughout your app which all get run and allow you to configure anything that is a "provider" during the first phase of execution. It then allows you to specify .run() blocks on the same module which are all run afterwards wherever they appear in code.

So, I understand VueJS is not a full framework but rather a view layer so I guess this is more of a question about how to implement this pattern in pure JS?

Comment: What kind of config do you want to do?

Comment: Do you mean lifecycle hooks? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: Yes, kind of, but more of a life cycle for the app. So for example let's say you're importing somebody else's modal window component and you want to configure something before all instances of the component are compiled on the page, even if your code is declared after theirs. In Angular you can use 'providers' which have methods which can only be called from config blocks and are all run during the config phase which happens before your html is compiled into a working app.

Comment: There's no configuration phase like with Angular. You can work with all your components, however, prior to instantiating your Vue. Rather than (like in Angular) there being some officially supported configuration process, Vue typically relies on just plain javascript. You can configure your components, plugins, mixins, what have you, or modify them in any way you like prior to instantiating your Vue.

Comment: Thanks Bert. I guess my brain is just too used to thinking in Angular and I just missed that you don't have to instantiate Vue until after everything else is done. So I can create my "providers" or "services" as normal JS singletons, configure them in whichever way I want and then just use them in my components which are compiled once Vue is instantiated. Happy to mark this as the right answer if you convert it to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official configuration process in Vue analogous to what there is in Angular. Essentially what you do in Vue is simply create, and configure any services, plugins, mixins, or what have you in your primary script prior to actually instantiating your Vue.

A good example might be the official VueRouter. A typical entry script for Vue would import the router component, configure the routes, instantiate the router, and **then** instantiate the root Vue (code below directly from the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html)).

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```